# Difficulty in understanding the proof concerning universal property for coproduct

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, coproduct

$\newcommand{\set}{\mathsf{Set}}\newcommand{\in}{\operatorname{in}}\newcommand{\pr}{\operatorname{pr}}$For the **Theorem:** below, can someone explain to me please how injectivity and surjectivity are demonstrated.  Looking at the proof, I am also not sure why the author used the sign post "conversely" in the proof since the theorem doesn't require an if and only if proof type strategy.

> **Theorem:**  (Universal property of coproduct)  Given two sets $a$ and $b$ and any set $c$, the function
>
> $$\gamma:\set(a\sqcup b,c)\xrightarrow{\cong}\set(a,c)\times\set(b,c)$$
> Defined by $\gamma(u)=(u\circ\in_a,u\circ\in_{b})$ is a bijection.

> Proof: Clearly, a map $u:a\sqcup b\rightarrow c$ is determined by its restrictions to its partitioning subsets $\{0\}\times a$ and $\{1\}\times b$, which in turn is equivalent to the pair $u\circ\in_{a}$ and $u\circ\in_{b}$ of maps.  So $\gamma$ is injective.  Conversely, if $v:a\rightarrow c$ and $w:b\rightarrow c$ are any two functions, then we define $u((0,x))=v(x)$ and $u((1,y))=w(y)$, which shows the surjectivity of $\gamma$.

I know that with the following definition coproduct for sets:

Definition a: A coproduct of $x$ and $y$ is an object $q$ with a pair of morphisms $f:x\rightarrow q$ and $g:y\rightarrow q$ with the following property:

> For any choice of objects $z$ and morphisms $f'x\rightarrow z$ and $g':y\rightarrow z$, there is a unique morphism $h:q\rightarrow z$ such that $h\circ f=f'$ and $g\circ h=g'$.

With that definition (Definition a), I can prove that:

> Any two coproducts of $x$ and $y$ are isomorphic.
>
> Proof:  Let $(q,f,g)$ and $(q',f',g')$ be coproducts, and let $z=q'$.  There are morphisms $f':x\rightarrow q'$ and $g':y\rightarrow q'$; and since $q$ is a coproduct, there is a unique morphism $h:q\rightarrow q'$ such that $h\circ f=f'$ and $h\circ g=g'$.  Similarly, there is a morphism $k:q'\rightarrow q$ such that $k\circ f'=f$ and $k\circ g'=g.$  We consider the morphisms $k\circ h$ and $1_q$ from $q$ to itself.  Then $(k\circ h)\circ f=k\circ(h\circ f) =k\circ f' =1_q\circ f=f$ and $(k\circ h)\circ g=k\circ(h\circ g) =k\circ g' =1_q\circ g=g$.  By the uniqueness part of the definition of a coproduct, $k\circ h=1_q$.   We similarly consider the morphisms $h\circ k$ and $1_{q'}$ from $q'$ to itself. Then $(h\circ k)\circ f'=h\circ(k\circ f') =h\circ f =1_{q'}\circ f'=f',$  $(h\circ k)\circ g'=h\circ(k\circ g') =h\circ g =1_{q'}\circ g'=g',$ hence $h\circ k=1_{q'}$.  Again, by the uniqueness part of the definition of a coproduct, $h\circ k=1_{q'}$.  Therefore $h$ and $k$ are inverses and each is an isomorphism.

The relevant definitions/notations and proposition for the **Theorem** are as follows:

Definition b:  Given two sets $a$ and $b$, the disjoint sum or coproduct $a\sqcup b$ of $a$ and $b=(\{0\}\times a)\cup (\{1\}\times b),$ together with the injections ${in}_a : a\rightarrow  a\sqcup b$ and ${in}_b : b\rightarrow  a\sqcup b$, where ${in}_a(x)=(0,x)$ and ${in}_b(y)=(1,y)$ for all $x \in a$ and $y \in b$.

Proposition 1:  If $a$ and $b$ are two sets then there is a set, denoted by $\set(a,b)$, whose elements are exactly the functions $f:a\rightarrow b$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to explain why you're confused by this proof, in more detail. The author demonstrates injectivity and surjectivity, and talks about "conversely" to signpost "thinking in the other direction". They just thought about starting with maps in the LHS and seeing what happens in the RHS, so in a way it is 'converse' to talk about maps in the RHS and see if they have preimages in the LHS

Comment: @FShrike I don't understand how what the author wrote demonstrated injectivity and surjectivity.  Usually when I see a proof that shows a map is bijective, it shows one to one, then onto.  So for one to one, it is either the classic $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$ or that a function is left cancelable.  Similarly for the case off surjectivity.  Also, I am not seeing that the map being asked to show bijection is an identity consisting of LHS and RHS.

Comment: "Is determined by" tells you uniqueness, i.e. injectivity

Comment: @FShrike can you explain how the author showed surjectivity.  I am not clear on that step also.  I did not know the phrase "is determined by" means that it shows uniqueness and hence injectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ u, v\colon a \sqcup b \to c$ be functions satisfying $ \gamma(u) = \gamma(v) $, that is, $ u \circ \text{in}_a = v \circ \text{in}_a $ and $ u \circ \text{in}_b = v \circ \text{in}_b $. Let $ (x,y) \in a \sqcup b $. If $ x = 0 $, then
$$ u((x,y)) = u(\text{in}_a(y)) = v(\text{in}_a(y)) = v((x,y)). 
$$
Similarly, if $ x = 1 $, then
$$ 
u((x,y)) = u(\text{in}_b(y)) = v(\text{in}_b(y)) = v((x,y)). 
$$
Therefore $ u = v $. This is what the "is determined by" part means. We have proven that $ \gamma $ is injective.

Regarding the surjectivity, look at the author's proof and note that for any $ x \in a $ and $ y \in b $,
$$
(u \circ \text{in}_a)(x) = 
u((0,x)) = v(x)
$$
and
$$
(u \circ \text{in}_b)(y) =
u((1,y)) = 
w(y).
$$
Therefore $ u \circ \text{in}_a = v $ and $ u \circ \text{in}_b = w $, so
$$
\gamma(u) = 
(u \circ \text{in}_a, u \circ \text{in}_b) =
(v, w).
$$
We have found an element of $ \text{Set}(a \sqcup b, c) $ which is mapped by $ \gamma $ to $ (v, w) $. This proves the surjectivity of $ \gamma $.

Comment: thank you so much for the clarification.  I really appreciate it.